# { "n_estimators" } are not used during Optuna Study

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, optuna

While performing optima study, I tried to tune `n_estimators` for xgboost in a binary classification problem, but I get:

```
WARNING: ../src/learner.cc:767: 
Parameters: { "n_estimators" } are not used.
```

Code :

```
def objective(trial):
    # Define the search space for hyperparameters
    params = {
        'objective': 'binary:logistic',  # For binary classification
        'eval_metric': 'auc',  # AUC-ROC as the evaluation metric
        'booster': 'gbtree',
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 0.3),
        'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 3, 10),
        'min_child_weight': trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 1, 10),
        'subsample': trial.suggest_float('subsample', 0.4, 1.0),
        'colsample_bytree': trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree', 0.55, 1.0),
        'lambda': trial.suggest_float('lambda', 1e-5, 1.0), 
        'alpha': trial.suggest_float('alpha', 1e-5, 1.0),  
        'eta': trial.suggest_float('eta', 0.01, 0.3), 
        'gamma': trial.suggest_float('gamma', 0.0, 1.0),  
        'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 100, 1300),
​
    }
​
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
​
    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
    dval = xgb.DMatrix(X_val, label=y_val)
​
    model = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=params['n_estimators'], evals=[(dval, 'eval')], verbose_eval=False)
    y_pred = model.predict(dval)
​
    auc_roc = roc_auc_score(y_val, y_pred)  # AUC-ROC score
​
    return -auc_roc
```

Comment: Seems an issue of XGBoost, not of Optuna.

Answer (score 1):

```py
xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=params['n_estimators'], ...)
```

Here you correctly unpack `n_estimators` as the value for the positional arg `num_boost_round` of xgboost's native `train`; but you *also* still have it in the `params` dictionary, where xgboost complains about it as an extraneous key.

So everything is probably working as intended already. To remove the warning, just remove that key from the dictionary; it can be in a separate variable, or you can pop it out after creating it.